# "NameError: name '' is not defined" after user input in Python

Tags: python

I'm completely lost as to why this isn't working. Should work precisely, right?

```
UserName = input("Please enter your name: ")
print ("Hello Mr. " + UserName)
raw_input("<Press Enter to quit.>")
```

I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "Test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    UserName = input("Please enter your name: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

It says `NameError 'k'`, because I wrote `'k'` as the input during my tests. I've read that the print statement used to be without parenthesis but that has been deprecated right?

Comment: `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.  You just want `raw_input()`.

Comment: input() is ok with Python 3k. @OP what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Sergio This is not related to your question, but you should use lowercase first letter for variable names (such as 'userName' instead of 'UserName').

Comment: I'm using the Python that came with Ubuntu. 2.6.4 I think. Can I install Python 3? SHOULD I install Python 3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do not use `input()` in 2.x. Use `raw_input()` instead. Always.

Comment: When was Input() used? In previous versions?

Comment: Yes. Python version 2.x.  http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-input

Comment: `input()` was always broken. 3.x "fixed" it, but the damage will take a long time to heal.

Comment: python 2 is dead, so i can always use 'input' instead of 'raw_input' now?

Answer (score 12):

In Python 2.x, `input()` "evaluates" what is typed in. (see `help(input)`). Therefore, when you key in `k`, `input()` tries to find what `k` is. Because it is not defined, it raises the `NameError` exception.

Use `raw_input()` in Python 2.x. In 3.0x, `input()` is fixed.

*If* you really want to use `input()` (and this is really not advisable), then quote your `k` variable as follows:

```
>>> UserName = input("Please enter your name: ")
Please enter your name: "k"
>>> print UserName
k
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer provides the correct solution and @ghostdog74 gives the reason for the exception. I figured it may be helpful to see, step by step, why this raises a `NameError` (and not something else, like ValueError):

As per Python 2.7 documentation, [`input()` evaluates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) what you enter, so essentially your program becomes this:

```
username = input('...')
# => translates to
username = eval(raw_input('...'))
```

Let's assume input is `bob`, then this becomes:

```
username = eval('bob')
```

Since `eval()` executes 'bob' as if it were a Python expression, your program becomes this:

```
username = bob 
=> NameError
print ("Hello Mr. " + username)
```

You *could* make it work my entering "bob" (with the quotes), because then the program is valid:

```
username = "bob" 
print ("Hello Mr. " + username)
=> Hello Mr. bob
```

You can try it out by going through each step in the [Python REPL](http://repl.it/languages/Python) yourself. Note that the exception is raised on the first line already, not within the print statement.