# Basic Python: exceptions.NameError

Tags: python-2.7

I'm still new to python and I've encountered a problem that I have no idea how to deal with. I'm creating a program where the user inputs their name and then the program outputs "Hello" alongside their name. I've left the code below:

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print ("Hello " + name)
```

However, when I run this and enter a name it throws up this message:

```
exceptions.NameError: name 'bob' is not defined
```

In this case I inputted 'bob' by the way.
Can anyone help me out? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: input() evaluates what you enter, so essentially your statement becomes `name = input('...') => eval(raw_input('...')) => eval('bob')` this is the same as if you wrote `name = bob` => NameError. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input

Comment: sorry, im still quite new to programming so coulf you explain that a bit more? sorry :)

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27676242/890242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `raw_input()` instead:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
print ("Hello " + name)
```

Mostly the difference between them is that `input(prompt)` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`. You can read more details [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Comment: sorry i cant i dont have enough reputation