# For loop and If condition- python

Tags: python-2.7

I try to run this code and write "hello" but get en error:

```
Value = input("Type less than 6 characters: ")
LetterNum = 1
for Letter in Value: 
    print("Letter ", LetterNum, " is ", Letter)
    LetterNum+=1
    if LetterNum > 6:
        print("The string is too long!")
        break
```

get error:

```
>>> 
Type less than 6 characters: hello

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yaron.KAYAMOT/Desktop/forBreak.py", line 1, in <module>
    Value = input("Type less than 6 characters: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
>>>
```

i don't know why it don't work

Comment: In Python 2.x, use `raw_input`

Comment: possible duplicate of ["NameError: name '' is not defined" after user input in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090706/nameerror-name-is-not-defined-after-user-input-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: use `raw_input()`

---

That is because `input()` in Python 2.7 tries to [evaluate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) your input (literally: `hello` is interpreted the same way as it will be written in your code):

```
>>> input("Type less than 6 characters: ")
Type less than 6 characters: 'hello'
'hello'
```

The word `hello` is parsed as variable, so `input()` complains the same way interpreter will do:

```
>>> hello
...
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
>>> input()
hello
...
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
>>> hello = 1
>>> hello
1
>>> input()
hello
1
```

Use `raw_input()` instead which returns raw string:

```
>>> raw_input("Type less than 6 characters: ")
Type less than 6 characters: hello
'hello'
```

This design flaw was fixed in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **raw_input()** instead of input().

according to [document](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input)

input([prompt]) Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

If input is some numbers,you may use 'input()'.But you should better never use 'input()',use 'int(raw_input())' instead.

```
Value = raw_input("Type less than 6 characters: ")
LetterNum = 1
for Letter in Value: 
    print("Letter ", LetterNum, " is ", Letter)
    LetterNum+=1
    if LetterNum > 6:
        print("The string is too long!")
        break

Type less than 7 characters: hello
('Letter ', 1, ' is ', 'h')
('Letter ', 2, ' is ', 'e')
('Letter ', 3, ' is ', 'l')
('Letter ', 4, ' is ', 'l')
('Letter ', 5, ' is ', 'o')
```

Comment: *"input() is for numbers"* - not really. You should pretty much never use it.

Comment: It's my fault. my english is not very good. "input() is for numbers"  is not precisely.